Creating a Two-dimensional NumPy Array from a Database Resultset
I have created a table yokes in a PostgreSQL database:
mydb=# CREATE TABLE yokes(id INT, name TEXT, size FLOAT);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# INSERT INTO yokes(id, name, size) VALUES(1, 'foo', 0.5);
INSERT 0 1
mydb=# INSERT INTO yokes(id, name, size) VALUES(2, 'bar', 1.5);
INSERT 0 1
mydb=# SELECT * FROM yokes;
 id | name | size 
----+------+------
  1 | foo  |  0.5
  2 | bar  |  1.5
(2 rows)

I want to turn that into a numpy array with shape (2, 3). My first approach was this:
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT id, name, size FROM yokes')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
arr = np.array(rows, dtype='i4, U8, f8')
print(arr.shape)

That gives me the output (2,), not the (2, 3) that I am aiming at. I assume, that this is because rows is a list of tuples.  Next try:
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='mydb')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT id, name, size FROM yokes')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
rows = [list(row) for row in rows]
arr = np.array(rows)
print(arr.shape)
print(arr.dtype)

Output:
(2, 3)
<U32

The shape is what I want.  But the second line shows that all values are now strings which is not what I want.
I have tried adding an argument dtype='i4, U8, f8 to np.array but that gives me an error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'" that I totally did not expect, because I specified the second (name) column to be of type U8 and not <i4.
Python, leave alone NumPy, is not my forte.  So, do not be afraid of being rookie-friendly.

Probably it would be easier to use Pandas here. NumPy is not great at handling heterogenous types.

Thanks! That helped. I omitted all string columns from the query so that I deal with just numbers. That works.
